# Get only distinct values from an ngrx store selector

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a function which checks whether a grid has loaded or not and if not it triggers the loading. But currently this ends up firing several times for the same `Loaded` value so it will call the relevant action multiple times. I was under the impression that store selectors emit by default only distinct (changed) values?

My function

```
private gridLoaded(filters: FilteredListingInput): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.settings.states.Loaded.pipe(
        tap(loaded => {
            this.logService.debug(
                `Grid ID=<${
                    this.settings.id
                }> this.settings.states.Loaded state = ${loaded}`
            );

            // Now we get duplicate firings of this action.
            if (!loaded) {
                this.logService.debug(
                    `Grid Id=<${
                        this.settings.id
                    }> Dispatching action this.settings.stateActions.Read`
                );

                this.store.dispatch(
                    new this.settings.stateActions.Read(filters)
                );
            }
        }),
        filter(loaded => loaded),
        take(1)
    );
}
```

`this.settings.states.Loaded` is selector from NgRx store.
The logging output I get looks like this:

```
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> this.settings.states.Loaded state = false {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid Id=<grid-reviewItem> Dispatching action this.settings.stateActions.Read {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> this.settings.states.Loaded state = true {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> Calling FilterClientSide action. Loaded=true {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> this.settings.states.Loaded state = true {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> Calling FilterClientSide action. Loaded=true {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> this.settings.states.Loaded state = true {ignoreIntercept: true}
Grid ID=<grid-reviewItem> Calling FilterClientSide action. Loaded=true {ignoreIntercept: true}
```

How can I make sure that the relevant actions are triggered only once?

**Edit - updates**

Selector code:

```
export const getReviewItemsLoaded = createSelector(
    getReviewItemState,
    fromReviewItems.getReviewItemsLoaded
);

export const getReviewItemState = createSelector(
    fromFeature.getForecastState,
    (state: fromFeature.ForecastState) => {
        return state.reviewItems;
    }
);

export const getReviewItemsLoaded = (state: GridNgrxState<ReviewItemListDto>) =>
    state.loaded;

export interface GridNgrxState<TItemListDto> {
    allItems: TItemListDto[];
    filteredItems: TItemListDto[];
    totalCount: number;
    filters: FilteredListingInput;
    loaded: boolean;
    loading: boolean;
    selectedItems: TItemListDto[];
}
```

As you can see we are just getting the `state.loaded` property, it's a trivial selector.

**Reducers** that change the `loading` property:

```
export function loadItemsSuccessReducer(state: any, action: GridAction) {
    const data = action.payload;

    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        totalCount: data.totalCount ? data.totalCount : data.items.length,
        allItems: data.items
    };
}

export function loadItemsReducer(state: any, action: GridAction) {
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        filters: action.payload
    };
}

export function loadItemsFailReducer(state: any, action: GridAction) {
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: false
    };
}
```

**Actions**

```
export class LoadReviewItemsAction implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_REVIEWITEMS;
    constructor(public payload?: FilteredListingInput) {}
}

export class LoadReviewItemsFailAction implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_REVIEWITEMS_FAIL;
    constructor(public payload: any) {}
}

export class LoadReviewItemsSuccessAction implements Action {
    readonly type = LOAD_REVIEWITEMS_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: PagedResultDtoOfReviewItemListDto) {}
```

**Effects**

```
export class ReviewItemsEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private reviewItemApi: ReviewItemApi
    ) {}

    @Effect()
    loadReviewItems$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(reviewItemActions.LOAD_REVIEWITEMS)
        .pipe(
            switchMap((action: reviewItemActions.LoadReviewItemsAction) => {
                return this.getDataFromApi(action.payload);
            })
        );

    /**
     * Retrieves and filters data from API
     */
    private getDataFromApi(filters: FilteredListingInput) {
        return this.reviewItemApi.getReviewItems(filters || {}).pipe(
            map(
                reviewItems =>
                    new reviewItemActions.LoadReviewItemsSuccessAction(
                        reviewItems
                    )
            ),
            catchError(error =>
                of(new reviewItemActions.LoadReviewItemsFailAction(error))
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There's `distinct` operator https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/distinct. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: the `createSelector` is memoized, so it shouldn't execute if the input parameters remain the same. From the code shared it's hard to say what's going wrong - if you have a stackblitz I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: This could happen if you override the state object, so its reference changes and selector emits every time. For more info please provide the whole chain - selector, reducer, action

Comment: @martin What I need actually is `distinctUntilChanged` however it didn't work. I've tried this without success: ```return this.settings.states.Loaded.pipe(distinctUntilChanged()).pipe(
            tap(loaded => {
                //... handle loading
            }),
            filter(loaded => loaded),
            take(1)
        );``` Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: @timdeschryver Hard to post a working stackblitz as it's a quite complex component. But I've posted more relevant code. Also posted my current functional workaround for this.

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius I've posted all the relevant actions, reducers, effects. In the meantime also posted the workaround that I'm using now as a partial answer. In the reducer don't I need to return a new state object every time instead of mutating the existing state object?

Comment: Yes, you can't mutate anything in reducers. It is not clear for me where this `this.settings.states.Loaded.` comes from. Is it output selector? Maybe its input selector, so is called many times

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius This (seemingly trivial) selector gets passed in as that `this.settings.states.Loaded` setting parameter: ```export const getReviewItemsLoaded = (state: GridNgrxState<ReviewItemListDto>) =>
    state.loaded;```

Comment: @JuliusDzidzevičius Actually the selector is the following (it just uses the `getReviewItemsLoaded` function: ```export const getReviewItemsLoaded = createSelector(
    getReviewItemState,
    fromReviewItems.getReviewItemsLoaded
);```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the issue by refactoring the `gridLoaded` method into `waitForGridLoaded` and moving some of its logic outside of it. This works well but I couldn't solve the original issue of why the `tap(loaded => ...)` logic is triggered many times.

Now the relevant bits look like this (it doesn't feel like the nicest solution):

```
private initializeLoadingState() {
    const loadingStateSubscription = this.settings.states.Loading.subscribe(
        loading => {
            this.loading = loading;
        }
    );
    this.addSubscription(loadingStateSubscription);
}

private initializeLoadedState() {
    const loadedStateSubscription = this.settings.states.Loaded.subscribe(
        loaded => {
            this.loaded = loaded;
        }
    );
    this.addSubscription(loadedStateSubscription);
}

onLazyLoad(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    // Do nothing yet if we are expecting to set parent filters
    // but we have not provided any parent filter yet
    if (
        this.settings.features.ParentFilters &&
        (!this.parentFiltersOnClient ||
            !this.parentFiltersOnClient.length) &&
        (!this.parentFiltersOnServer || !this.parentFiltersOnServer.length)
    ) {
        return;
    }

    this.loadAndFilterItems(event);
}

private loadAndFilterItems(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    if (this.settings.features.ClientSideCaching) {
        if (this.loaded) {
            // Load only once and filter client side
            this.store.dispatch(
                new this.settings.stateActions.FilterClientSide(
                    this.buildFilters(event, GridParentFilterTypes.Client)
                )
            );
        } else if (!this.loading) {
            // Start loading in from server side
            this.store.dispatch(
                new this.settings.stateActions.Read(
                    this.buildFilters(event, GridParentFilterTypes.Server)
                )
            );

            // When we have finished loading, apply any client side filters
            const gridLoadedSubscription = this.waitForGridLoaded().subscribe(
                loaded => {
                    if (loaded) {
                        this.store.dispatch(
                            new this.settings.stateActions.FilterClientSide(
                                this.buildFilters(
                                    event,
                                    GridParentFilterTypes.Client
                                )
                            )
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
            this.addSubscription(gridLoadedSubscription);
        }
    } else {
        this.store.dispatch(
            new this.settings.stateActions.Read(
                this.buildFilters(event, GridParentFilterTypes.Server)
            )
        );
    }
}

private waitForGridLoaded(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.settings.states.Loaded.pipe(
        filter(loaded => loaded),
        take(1)
    );
}
```